# why onload function is being called twice, though component is rendering once?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having a simple react component, the fire is printed once, but injectWindowInterval is called twice event though i am setting flag value, why is it so?

```
const Header = () => {
  let flag = true;
  
  console.log("fire");  

  function injectWindowInterval() {
    if (flag && window.google) {
      flag = false;
      console.log(window.google);
    }
  }

  const script = document.createElement("script");
  script.src = "https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client";
  script.onload = injectWindowInterval;
  script.async = true;
  document.querySelector("body")?.appendChild(script);

  return (
    <div className="header">
      <h3 className="header__title">RE</h3>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Update: for some reason, the script is appending twice in body.

Comment: If you are cheking the console while developing then it could be possible that you are running code in `React.StrictMode` mode. Navigate to `index.js` and see that whether you have wrapper `App` component in `React.StrictMode` or not.

Comment: Which React version do you use?

Comment: @decpk yes, using React.StrictMode, but function is rendering once only i.e "fire" is printed once.

Comment: @lukasl-dev using 17.0.2

Answer (score 1):

In some cases function are called on render when they are defined. One common example is with onClick methods for buttons

```
<button onClick={onClickFunction}>Click me</button> //fires on render
<button onClick={()=>onClickFunction()}>Click me</button> //no fire on render, works well
```

So maybe try

```
const Header = () => {
  let flag = true;
  
  console.log("fire");  


  const script = document.createElement("script");
  script.src = "https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client";
  script.onload = () => {
    if (flag && window.google) {
      flag = false;
      console.log(window.google);
    }
  };
  script.async = true;
  document.querySelector("body")?.appendChild(script);

  return (
    <div className="header">
      <h3 className="header__title">RE</h3>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Same issue tried above.
The script tag is appending twice for some reason, i think that's why it is being called twice.

Comment: Ah ok, i don't know how to write this but maybe try to .appendChild(script) conditionally, if body contains script with let's say scr="accounts.google..." then do not appendChild ?

Comment: have made a workaround for now using other flow, but still this seems weird behaviour in react.

Answer (score 0):

If you are rendering the Component in <React.StrictMode>, the component will render twice for sure in development mode.
I tried rendering above component(Header) and the fire is logged in the console twice so do the script tag appended twice.
[Here is the console Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGytI.png)

Note : Also note that React renders component twice only in development mode. Once you build the app the component will be rendered only once.